# What is packet size and average packet size?

Tags: networking, ping

I am playing Halo 2 Project Cartographer and I wanted to see my ping (because Halo doesn't allows you to see your ping by default, it shows only your stability), so i typed in the console the "netstats" command, and it showed me 2 parameters: packets per seconds and average packet size. Which of these values shows my ping?

Comment: See https://www.lifewire.com/definition-of-mtu-817948

Answer (score 3):

"ping" is short for "ping time" which is a shorthand way of  referring to your "round-trip time" (RTT). These are measures of latency (lag). Specifically, they are measures of how long it takes packets to make the round-trip from your computer, to the target machine (in your case the Halo game server), and back to your machine.

Neither your packets per second nor your average packet size tells you anything about your RTT, nor can you calculate your RTT from those two pieces of data.